# Is having multiple classes in an element a good (or best) practice?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is having multiple classes in a single element a good practice? Like so:

```
<div class ="panel panel-primary panel-hide text-center">
```

Or is it better to do this:

```
<div class ="panel">
    <div class="panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-hide">
            <div class="text-center">
             <!-- content here -->
```

Or is it better to limit classes to 2 or 3 per div?

Or does it even matter?

Comment: use as many as you have too and as fewer as needed.

Comment: Thanks @claudiu. You mean as few divs as needed? So basically try to places all classes in 1 div?

Comment: According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes), classes should describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe the desired presentation of the content. So `text-center` is a bad class. And add all classes to the same element or to different elements depending on the content.

Comment: Thanks Oriol. I used those classes as a example. `text-center` need not be there. It could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you got some of these classes and pieces of code from the Bootstrap website?

Sometimes classes need to be on separate nested divs, because they use :before and :after or margin, padding or positioning for that div. When you paste all classes inside one div, this may not work, and classes may overwrite eachother.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the project, what you're trying to accomplish, and what pre-existing helpers you're using.

If you're using something like Twitter Bootstrap, use what you're given to accomplish what you need in the least amount of code.

If you're building something with custom classes, stick with one pattern and follow through. You want to be conscious of why you're adding a class, otherwise you can run into specificity problems later down the line and resort to adding more on top just to pinpoint a particular element.

If adding a class will save 10 lines of repeated code, as you repeat the same styles with like items, absolutely go for it. However, I like to try to keep the classes as streamlined as possible.

A very boiled down example:

**THIS**

```
<div class="one">
   <p>
       <h1>Hi there!</h1>
   </p>
</div>

.one {
    /* css here */
}

.one > p {
    /* more css here */
}

.one > p > h1 {
    /* even more css here */
}
```

**COULD WORK INSTEAD OF ALL THIS**

```
<div class="one">
   <p class="one-p">
       <h1 class="one-header">Hi there!</h1>
   </p>
</div>

.one {
    /* css here */
}

.one .one-p {
    /* more css here */
}

.one .one-p .one-header {
    /* even more css here */
}
```