# Is having multiple rows and columns inside one another an okay practice in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am structuring the HTMl on my page as follows:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="container-2">
                        <div class="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are 6 divs outside of the actual content on each section. The outer column is to be a container of a certain colour, and the inner container is only fill up 8/12 of the outer container. This produces margins with the background colour of the outer container of width 2 on either side of the inner column.

This looks great and is responsive. However, I'm wondering if having this many divs is good practice or not?

Comment: Check this link for more information: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/why-too-many-divs-is-bad-practice/7754

Comment: Your question is looking to similar this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376773/is-having-multiple-classes-in-an-element-a-good-or-best-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess it's up to you. If you feel like you can manage this many div's then it's fine. But what you have to think about is, if you for instance would pass on your project to another developer, then he would need to understand your work without cleaning up before he even starts, so it's always important to have that in mind when you develop.

I would maybe construct it this way:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just what I wan't to do, maybe someone else would do it another way.